# How to add two calendars in a page - Joomla

Tags: joomla3.0

I am new to joomla, want to implement two calendars in a page ...

```
 From : 
    <?php
    echo JHTML::calendar('sch_from', 'sch_from', '%Y-%m-%d');
    ?>
 To :
    <?php
    echo JHTML::calendar('sch_to', 'sch_to', '%Y-%m-%d');
    ?>
```

But first calendar only working... is there any issue in code?

Answer (score 0):

syntax is:

```
JHtml::calendar($value,'nameOfField','idOfField', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

located at libraries/cms/html/html.php

try

```
From : 
    <?php
    echo JHTML::calendar('','sch_from', 'sch_from', '%Y-%m-%d');
    ?>
To :
    <?php
    echo JHTML::calendar('','sch_to', 'sch_to', '%Y-%m-%d');
    ?>
```